# iostat report huge writes to drives that's not even mounted

Tags: io, fsck, lsof

```
root@host [~]# fsck /home2
fsck from util-linux-ng 2.17.2
e2fsck 1.41.12 (17-May-2010)
/dev/sdb1: clean, 6018617/91578368 files, 54524459/366284000 blocks
root@host [~]# fsck /home4
fsck from util-linux-ng 2.17.2
e2fsck 1.41.12 (17-May-2010)
/dev/sdd1: clean, 8094369/91578368 files, 75999625/366284000 blocks
```

fsck returns no error

```
root@host [~]# lsof /home4
root@host [~]# lsof /home2
```

lsof returns no user

```
root@host [~]# mount
/dev/mapper/VolGroup-lv_root on / type ext4 (rw,relatime,usrjquota=quota.user,jqfmt=vfsv0)
proc on /proc type proc (rw)
sysfs on /sys type sysfs (rw)
devpts on /dev/pts type devpts (rw,gid=5,mode=620)
tmpfs on /dev/shm type tmpfs (rw,rootcontext="system_u:object_r:tmpfs_t:s0")
/dev/sda1 on /boot type ext4 (rw)
/dev/mapper/VolGroup-lv_home on /home type ext4 (rw,relatime,usrjquota=quota.user,jqfmt=vfsv0)
/dev/sdc1 on /home3 type ext3 (rw,relatime)
none on /proc/sys/fs/binfmt_misc type binfmt_misc (rw)
/usr/tmpDSK on /tmp type ext3 (rw,noexec,nosuid,loop=/dev/loop0)
/tmp on /var/tmp type none (rw,noexec,nosuid,bind)
sunrpc on /var/lib/nfs/rpc_pipefs type rpc_pipefs (rw)
root@host [~]# iostat -xk
Linux 2.6.32-279.19.1.el6.x86_64 (host.buildingsuperteams.com)  01/06/2013      _x86_64_        (16 CPU)

avg-cpu:  %user   %nice %system %iowait  %steal   %idle
          18.91    0.02   39.17   20.22    0.00   21.67
```

mount shows that there is sdd1 and sdb1 is not mounted

```
Device:         rrqm/s   wrqm/s     r/s     w/s    rkB/s    wkB/s avgrq-sz avgqu-sz   await  svctm  %util
sda               0.16    11.93    1.35    3.30    53.91    59.92    48.95     0.10   21.87   3.70   1.72
sdb               0.49   219.57   22.00   99.14   224.17  1275.44    24.76     7.44   61.38   7.45  90.24
sdd               0.46   226.39   23.26   92.71   260.61  1277.34    26.52     0.67    5.77   7.71  89.40
sdc               0.00     1.79    0.28    0.05     5.03     7.38    74.28     0.00   14.34   2.05   0.07
dm-0              0.00     0.00    1.45   14.91    53.66    59.50    13.83     1.56   95.36   1.06   1.73
dm-1              0.00     0.00    0.04    0.10     0.18     0.41     8.00     0.00   21.25   2.44   0.04
dm-2              0.00     0.00    0.01    0.00     0.05     0.01     8.49     0.00    7.32   1.84   0.00
```

iostat report huge writes

What would the reason be? I will replace the hard disk anyway. But this puzzles me to no end

This caused a server crash already. I unmout the drive.

iostat -x 1 shows empty, which is what's expected. So all this time I saw past data?

Comment: Those are averages. Try `iostat -x 1` to see realtime data.

Comment: Did you setup raid 1?

Comment: What is raid? In short no.

Comment: Raid1 is drive mirroring. For example, if sdb and sdd are mirrored, they are Raid 1.

Comment: Don't think I do that.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It is possible your `VolGroup-lv_root` is created on that drive. Check output of following command

```
pvs
```

It display physical volumes information about LV.

More info about LVM ([1](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Logical_Volume_Manager_%28Linux%29)), ([2](http://www.web-manual.net/linux-3/logical-volume-manager-in-linux/)), ([3](http://www.markus-gattol.name/ws/lvm.html))